# Prevent requests to internal resources on a CDN

Tags: node.js, security, networking, request, localhost

Under this context, firewalls exist for a reason: to block external requests from accessing internal resources.

So say I have two HTTP servers running: one on port 8080, and one on port 8081.

The server on port 8080 is a publicly accessible Node-based website (powered by `express` in this example), and runs the following code on every request, which is basically a simple sort of CDN that requests data from a user-defined URL (in the `X-Cool-URL` header) and returns that request's body to the user under my website's domain. `request` is the `request` module, `req` is the `express` request object, and `res` is the `express` response object. (Obviously this particular code is not practical or error-proof, but it is a decent example.)

```
const url = req.get("X-Cool-URL"); // some example user input value
request(url, (error, response, body) => { // request said arbitrary resource
    res.send(body); // send response back to user
});
```

The server on port 8081 is an HTTP server that does things via internal requests; external networking through port 8081 is blocked off by a firewall, and for a good reason. Arbitrary user-defined data should never be sent to it. Assume that I am not the programmer of this web server and have no control over or access to its code. What exactly this server does with any given request input is irrelevant. All that matters is that allowing arbitrary data to be sent to it would be a security risk.

...but I can run this command from any external command line.

```
curl -H "X-Cool-URL: http://localhost:8081/something/malicious" http://example.com:8080
```

This poses a problem: users can just use my public web server to request the private web server through `localhost:8081` under internal networking. I still want people to be able to request other public domains through my web server on port 8080, and I still want to be able to internally request 8081 as a developer, but I don't want anyone else to be able to exploit my server for arbitrary access to 8081, free of the firewall. How can I make it so users cannot possibly use my public web server to request any internal resources?

The port I want to protect might not always be definite and known, so it wouldn't be practical simply to block 8081 through my web server. It also wouldn't be practical to only block all requests to `localhost`, as there are other ways to request internal resources (such as using `127.0.0.1`). It is even possible to set up DNS records the point to local resources, so just blacklisting a set of URLs wouldn't work either. Whitelisting is also not an option as it would defeat the point of the CDN, for the client to be able to request any external resource. I am interested in a way which works in every case to detect whether or not a URL is internal.

Comment: Which server do you control? The proxy serving on port 8080 or the one  behind it serving port 8081?

Comment: Hypothetically, I only control the one on 8080.

Answer (score 1):

#### Case 1: You control the proxy server on port 8080

So if you control the proxy server but not the web server behind it, then it's actually quite simple to prevent things like this: You simply need to filter certain HTTP headers from the request and *not* process those request.

Safest would be to work with a whitelist of hostnames you allow to be used in the `X-Cool-URL` header. Then simply check if the URL matches the white list. Alternatively you can filter using a blacklist but that's a bit more troublesome as you have to consider not only `localhost`, but also various IP ranges. You don't want `X-Cool-URL` to point to anything like 127.0.0.1, 192.168.x.x, etc.

#### Case 2: You control the backend server on port 8081

If you have no control over which requests the proxy server filters and what HTTP requests it forwards to you, you will have to check where the request is coming from instead. You can get details about the original requestor using code like this:

```
var ip = req.headers['x-forwarded-for'] || req.connection.remoteAddress;
```

If the `ip` address isn't in your allowed range, don't answer the request. This way you can grant access from other servers that run behind your firewall while preventing access from the proxy.

#### Developer Access

Once you have either one of these two mechanics implemented, you still want to allow development access to the backend. Simplest would be to use a secret key that only you know and that cannot be guessed easily. Then provide this secret key either as an additional HTTP request header (`X-Cool-Secret`) or as part of the `X-Cool-URL` itself as a query parameter.

#### Additional Musings

Scenarios like this are inherently unsafe. As soon as you provide access to your backend through the public Internet you need to be prepared for attacks. Even if your proxy can filter a lot there's still the chance that someone finds a way through it. Having both the proxy and the backend run on the same physical machine (or VM) adds additional security risks. General rule of thumb: Don't do it.

Allowing access from development machines is also risky. Keys can leak, passwords can be stolen, IP addresses can be spoofed. There's no simple way of preventing sophisticated attacks. This public access has many tradeoffs that you usually should avoid. Try digging into using SSH as a secure tunnel into your demilitarized zone (everything behind the firewall and proxy) instead. This offers a much more secure environment that you can build yourself in Node/Express.

Hope that helps nonetheless.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer, but unfortunately none of this fully applies to the situation. A whitelist is too restrictive, and a blacklist cannot definitively be restrictive enough. As for the second solution, the case is that I _don't_ have access to the 8081 server. Otherwise I would be able to use some sort of authentication, as you referenced in "Developer Access". In actual application, I'll likely just remove this system entirely, considering its security flaw and that I don't actually need it for my web server to work. I really only asked this question out of hypothetical curiosity.

Comment: You _need_ to find a criteria to distinguish allowed and forbidden requests and filter incoming requests by that. Worst case scenario is the blacklist though it can be made relatively secure by excluding any direct IP address access and well-known internal host names. If you have more detail about the specific situation, maybe there's a more suitable solution. Nonetheless I would appreciate if you accept this as an answer if you don't wait for any others anymore.